# Send email with URL of same page as the email link?

Tags: emails

We have a page that displays a logged-in user's selections from a Flag Lists process. The page includes code to generate the specific URL of that page, so it can be copied and pasted elsewhere. (essentially a "share this" type of thing, but this is definitely not intended for social media) That code is:
    " onclick="this.select();" />

We want to provide an email link (ideally, a button) which sends a preformatted message including this URL, to a specific person's email address. (i.e. always to the same person) I am having trouble visualizing how this can be done, since the interface I am using for adding an email link (via CK Editor) isn't able to process the "current-page:url" PHP code and just displays it as code in the resulting message.

Any suggestions? -- Thanks! --

Answer (score 0):

insert a Drupal `token` of the `current page url` into the WYSIWYG. This token is provided by drupal 7 core I believe.

See the [Token Insert](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_insert) module.

> This module allows you to insert tokens into a textarea. It supports
>   both plain text and wysiwyg textareas. The format used for the insert
>   is compatible with Token Filter.
>
> This module contains three modules:
>
> - Token Insert UI: Allows you to select which tokens are available for
>     the insert, by default all tokens are shown. This module doesn't have
>     to be enabled to use the others.
> - Token Insert (text): Add a fieldset
>     under each textarea, works for both plain text fields and wysiwyg
>     fields.
> - Token Insert (wysiwyg): Adds an extra button to wysiwyg
>     editors and opens a popup to select the token to insert.